# Limits in category theory and analysis

Tags: ct.category-theory, limits-and-convergence, limits-and-colimits

Is it possible to regard limits in analysis (say, of real sequences or more generally nets in topological spaces) as limits in category theory? Is there some formal connection?

Edit ('13): Perhaps it is more interesting to ask whether limits in category theory can be seen as special limits of ultrafilters or nets.

Comment: This was previously addressed here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/6554/terminology-in-category-theory

Comment: Twice, in fact.

Comment: I'm not really satisfied with the answers. if we consider the partial order of open subsets of X, a diagram in this category has nothing to do with a net/sequence.

Comment: While not the answer to your question you might be interested in considering the natural ordering of the L^p spaces on measurable eu sets, now take the direct limit. Notice that depending on the category in which you take the spaces to be objects, you may, or may not get L^/infty. I found this excercise very amusing when I first considered it. 

Comment: I think that obstacle is that give a topology viewed as a category objects are open sets, and points (concept inherent to analysis limit concept) isn't descrivible in simple categorical way (a ultrafilter is topology is T1). THen need enrich the base, and considering the limits on a locales relative to its "point", or more generally in a topos on Set (where a point is a geometric morphism from Set). But this requires a more accurate exploration...

Comment: @Buschi: I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: @MArtin: Sorry for my ENglish (and mine no too linear mind maybe). From a topological space $X$ you get the ordered category $C(X)$ of its opens, then (considerind tha analysis definition of limit)  rise the question: "How detect (find) points of $X$ in terms of  the category $C(X)$?".  Points of $X$ come from the set sub-structure that is under (and out) $C(X)$. In  locales or (more generally) a topos  you have the concept of "points". (Is only a starting idea)        

Comment: I have asked this qouestion on math.stackexchange last year, and got sasisfactory answer, at least for me :) ( http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60590/category-theoretic-limit-related-to-topological-limit )

Comment: @rafaelm: Can you add this as an answer, please?

Comment: @Martin Brandenburg: Sure!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I have asked [this question on math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60590/category-theoretic-limit-related-to-topological-limit) last year, and got satisfying answer.
(So this construction did not come from me.)

Let $(X,\mathcal O)$ be a topological space, $\mathcal F(X)$ the partialy ordered set of filters on $X$ with respect to inclusions, considered as a small category in the usual way. Given $x\in X$ and $F\in\mathcal F(X)$ let $\mathcal U_X(x)$ denote the neighbourhood filter of $x$ in $(X,\mathcal O)$ and $\mathcal F_{x,F}(X)$ the full subcategory of $\mathcal F(X)$ generated by $\{G\in\mathcal F(X):F\cup\mathcal U_X(x)\subseteq G\}$, let $E:\mathcal F_{x,F}\hookrightarrow\mathcal F(X)$ be the obvious (embedding) diagram, $\Delta$ the usual diagonal functor and $\lambda:\Delta(F)\rightarrow E$ the natural transformation where $\lambda(G):F\hookrightarrow G$ is the inclusion for each $G\in\mathcal F_{x,F}$. It is not hard to see that $F$ tends to $x$ in $(X,\mathcal O)$ iff $\lambda$ is a limit of $E$.

Answer (score 19):

In very special cases, the notions coincide.  Let $R$ be the category (poset) whose objects are the real numbers and in which $Hom(x, y)$ has a single element if $x \leq y$ and is empty otherwise.  Then for a nonincreasing sequence of real numbers, its limit in the classical sense (if not $-\infty$) is also its limit in the categorical sense (if it exists).

Comment: Much more generally, metric spaces can be identified with certain categories enriched over [0,∞] with the opposite of the usual order, as realized by Lawvere in his paper "Metric spaces, generalized logic, and closed categories."  At least some limits of sequences or nets in metric spaces can then be identified with limits in the categorical sense.


Comment: I hope you don't mind a dumb question on an 8 year old post, but how should I think of a sequcence of numbers as being a diagram in category theory? (I hope that's the right question to ask. My confusion is that in category theory we speak of the limit of a diagram, so in order for a sequence to have a limit in the categorical sense, it seems like the sequence would have to correspond to a diagram.)

Comment: @Nathaniel Consider the category $J$ whose objects are natural numbers and there is a single morphism in $\mathop{\mathrm{Hom}}_J(x,y)$ whenever $x \le y$ and empty otherwise. Given a sequence of real numbers, $(a_n)$, there is a functor $F\colon J \to R$ assigning $F(n) = a_n$. The functor $F$ is the diagram in this example. A cone to $F$ is a real number which is a lower bound for the sequence $(a_n)$, so the limit of $F$ is the least upper bound, i.e. $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$ in the classical sense.

Comment: So, @Tyler, would the actual limit of a sequence be a zero object in the category of cones? I mean, if the limit of $F$ and the colimit are the same?

Answer (score 15):

I have always justified this to my self by thinking:

- A limit of a sequence is the "best approximation" of the sequence by a single point.
- A limit of a *diagram* is the "best approximation" of the diagram by a single *object*.

But to make the first into an instance of the second, one would need a category representing a topological space where points are objects. And I can't think of one right now.

Answer (score 7):

I agree with [Tom Leinster's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6554/terminology-in-category-theory/6564#6564) to the previous question.

To this I would add that I believe that the general usage of "limit" in category theory, ie including binary products and pullbacks, is due to Peter Freyd (in his thesis), whereas previously "projective" "inductive limits" had been indexed by N or ordinals.  This extension of the usage is another example of the over-stretching of language that Tom mentioned.

On the other hand, I also strongly agree with Martin that this answer is unsatifactory, but this does not mean that I think that any satisfactory answer can be given by referring to a single (contrived) example.

This is the kind of question that those (like
[me](http://PaulTaylor.EU/ASD/analysis)) who are interested in both category theory and analysis should come back to from time to time and reconsider.

Answer (score 3):

I am not completely satisfied by the accepted answer because the functor which characterizes the convergence of a filter depends on the limit. I therefore add another quite simple answer (written for sequences but this easily generalizes to filters and nets) to this old post.

---

The definition of a limit as a universal cone of a functor resembles the infimum (greatest lower bound) of a set in a very transparent way: Considering a partially ordered set $(X,\le)$ as a category with only one morphism from $x$ to $y$ if $x\le y$ and none otherwise, a subset $A$ of $X$ has an infimum if and only if the inclusion functor $A\hookrightarrow X$ has a limit. In particular, if the power set $\mathscr P(X)$ is ordered by inclusion the intersection of any subfamily $\mathscr A$ is a limit.

---

Let now $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence in some topological space $X$. Then the limit of the contravariant functor $F:\mathbb N\to \mathscr P(X)$ assigning to $n$ the set $F(n)=\overline{\{x_k:k\ge n\}}$ is the set of all limit points of the sequence.

I think that this is a strong relation between analytical and functorial limits although it does not yet characterize convergence of sequences. At least, if either $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space or $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a Cauchy sequence in a Hausdorff uniform space, the sequence converges if and only if the set of limit points is a singleton.

Comment: Why does it not yet characterize convergence of sequences? Would you know if this has been worked out somewhere?

Comment: The sequence $x_{2n}=n$ and $x_{2n+1}=0$ satisfies $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}\overline{\{x_k:k\ge n\}}=\{0\}$ but it diverges. I don't know whether this simple (and maybe superficial) *functorial interpretation* of convergence appears somewhere in the literature.

Answer (score 1):

I  think this doesn't quite work:

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the category whose objects are the point of $X$, and define
$$
\mathrm{mor}_\mathcal{C}(x,y) = \{ \mbox{closed sets containing both $x$ and $y$} \}.
$$
Composition is   union.

Now (for example) a sequence $\{ x_n\}$ in $X$ defines a functor $F: \mathbb{N} \to \mathcal{C}$ and a cone from $F$ to $y$ is essentially a single closed set 
containing the entire sequence and $y$. Since this set must contain the topological limit $x$ of the sequence, this means that the cone factors   through the same closed set viewed as a morphism $x\to y$, so $x$ is the categorical colimit of $F$.

And since the morphism sets are symmetrical, the sequence  $\{ x_n\}$ can be viewed as a contravariant functor $G: \mathbb{N}\to \mathcal{C}$, and the topological limit $x$ is the categorical limit of $G$.

PROBLEM:  the factorization is not unique!

Answer (score 0):

A more abstract version of the answer https://mathoverflow.net/a/120183 :

Recall that a filter $F$ has limit $x$ if all open sets containing $x$ are in $F$, equivalently, if

$$U_x\subseteq F$$

where $U_x$ is the filter of neighbourhoods of $x$.

Set up a diagram that contains all supersets of $F\cup U_x$. The limit of the diagram is the intersection of all these supersets, that is, $F\cup U_x$ itself.

It follows that $F$ is the limit of the diagam iff $F=F\cup U_x$, that is, iff $U_x\subseteq F$, that is, iff $F$ has limit $x$.