# Is there some way to see a Hilbert space as a C-enriched category?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, ct.category-theory, enriched-category-theory

The inner product of vectors in a Hilbert space has many properties in common with a hom functor.  I know that one can make a projectivized Hilbert space into a metric space with the Fubini-Study metric and then follow Lawvere in considering it a $[0,\infty)$-enriched category; it's particularly nice because the distance between two vectors is a function of the inner product.

Is there a way of defining a monoidal structure on $\mathbb{C}$ such that the inner product is the hom so that we can think of a (perhaps projectivized) Hilbert space as $\mathbb{C}$-enriched?

Comment: Related question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/476/can-adjoint-linear-transformations-be-naturally-realized-as-adjoint-functors

Comment: You might also be interested in John Baez's paper on the subject: http://arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9609018